I want to do a self join on a model using SQLAlchemy and then serialize it to JSON but get maximum recursion error
I have a User model like the following
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)

    hashed_password: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(256), nullable=False)

    created_by_id: so.Mapped[int | None] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='cascade'))
    
    @so.declared_attr
    def created_by(cls):
        return so.relationship("User", primaryjoin='User.id == User.created_by_id', remote_side=[cls.id], join_depth=1, single_parent=True)
    // other attributes ignored

then I do a self join in my code like this:
alias_user = aliased(User)
query = select(User) \
    .outerjoin(alias_user.created_by) \
    .options(defer(User.hashed_password))
results = await session.scalars(query)
results.unique()

then some where in my code I convert results into a json object using this:
jd = jsonable_encoder(list(results), exclude_none=True)

but I get the the following exeption:
jsonable_encoder recursionerror: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

how to change my code to prevent this exception?
Thanks in advance.

How many layers of "created by" do you want to include?

@MatsLindh just one

In that case, use FastAPIs built-in response_class on your endpoint, and have it use a model that contains UserWithCreatedByUser - that model contains the created_by_user-field, but with a UserWithoutCreatedByUser as the type of the created_by_user field.
